# HashRouter show File:// on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

Why my project show Index of folder when build, but when it running, it works

My Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ABC</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[When i call my index.html and my bundle.js after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytjVS.png)